# Kusto range function Semantic error: '' has the following semantic error: Unresolved reference binding:XXX"

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

```
let a = (arg0:long) {
    toscalar(
        Incidents
        | where IncidentId == arg0 
        | count)
};
range idx from 0 to 11 step 1 
| extend a(idx)
```

My kusto query string just like this, and it is easy to understand, but it cannot work.

Answer (score 0):

You're hitting limitations of user-defined functions, as they're documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/functions/user-defined-functions#restrictions-on-the-use-of-user-defined-functions

you should be able to achieve your goal by doing something like the following (matching the example you provided):

```
let count_by_incident_id = 
    Incidents 
    | summarize count() by IncidentId
;
range idx from 0 to 11 step 1
| join hint.strategy = broadcast (count_by_incident_id)
    on $left.idx == $right.IncidentId
```

Comment: So awesome solution... Thank you very much.

Comment: But if the filter is not equal but bigger, just like this, I don't konw how to use the join:
let a = (arg0:long) {toscalar(Incidents | where IncidentId >= arg0 | count)}; range idx from 0 to 11 step 1 | extend a(idx)

Comment: you may want to have a look at either of the following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/joinoperator#cross-join, or for datetime-values: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/join-timewindow